# How to get information from another Power BI table

Tags: powerbi

I have two tables, one where are the incidents created and the date (table1), and another where are the people who were on duty on those dates (table2).

Table1

[image]

Table2

[image]

what I am looking for is to create in my table1 the column called **"persona crea"** in which I want to bring the personnel that was on duty (from table2) on that date that the incident is created. the tables have nothing in common to relate them. I make this simple example because my powerbi data has a lot of information. I hope you can help me, I tried the **lookupvalue** but it works when the tables have something in common, but this is not the case.

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eygNO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a helper column to generate the desired relationship.

The time stamps in **fecha inicio** seem to indicate that there is only one person per shift and that the shifts start either at midnight or at noon. If that is an established pattern, you can create a helper column in the Table1 that uses a calculation based on **fecha crea**. The formula would need to round down the value in `fecha crea` to previous noon or midnight. With that, you have the lookup value you need for a join or a relationship.

The custom column could be added with Power Query or with Dax, depending on where you get the data from and what method you prefer.

Conceptually, in Power Query, I'd use this approach:

- get the hour value for `fecha crea`
- if the hour value is less than 12, return a 0, otherwise return a 12
- remove the time from the `fecha crea` value
- add a time stamp using the hour value you just established.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: what happens is that the changes are not at midnight or noon, sometimes it is at 09:00 hrs, at 14:00 hrs, etc. add a photo to my question

Comment: OK, you need to develop some logic by which you can determine how the two tables are connected. If you cannot explain the connection between the tables with words, then you won't be able to create a reference. Such a reference can only use an exact match, not a match with a comparison like "greater than" or "later than xx:xx". So, is there any procedure or logic that can be used? Maybe there is a shift timetable somewhere with dates and start times of the shift? If not, maybe such a timetable can be built and added to the data model. ... cont...

Comment: ... cont... The idea here is that a value from a wide time range must be evaluated to result in a single point in time which can be used for the lookup relationship. Before a formula can be built, this logic must be described in words.

Comment: This is the logic that I think can be applied in power bi. but I don't know what functions to use